# 2021: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, site-statistics

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.

So as we say goodbye to 2021, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZntT.gif). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Role-playing Games over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 4 | 20 |
| Users destroyed³ | 92 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 1 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 10 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 106 | 1,751 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 6 | 1,398 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 8 | 2,148 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 3 | 706 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First questions queue | 6 | 175 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 8 | 1,294 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First answers queue | 6 | 294 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 10 | 3,279 |
| Tags merged | 7 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 25 | 2 |
| Tag synonyms created | 31 | 0 |
| Revisions redacted | 11 | 0 |
| Questions unprotected | 2 | 7 |
| Questions reopened | 31 | 259 |
| Questions protected | 1 | 172 |
| Questions migrated | 5 | 2 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 15 | 649 |
| Questions closed | 113 | 1,022 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 265 | 369 |
| Posts unlocked | 0 | 1 |
| Posts undeleted | 30 | 164 |
| Posts locked | 4 | 145 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 247 | 1,656 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 54 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 3 | 0 |
| Comments undeleted | 125 | 0 |
| Comments flagged | 13 | 3,685 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 8,471 | 4,458 |
| Comment flags handled | 3,341 | 361 |
| Bounties canceled | 1 | 0 |
| Answers flagged | 53 | 2,423 |
| Answer flags handled | 810 | 1,664 |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 82 | 0 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2020: a year in moderation](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11355/2020-a-year-in-moderation)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222021%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374784/208518)

Wishing everyone a happy 2022! ^_^

Comment: I'm not seeing "questions merged", am I right to assume we had zero?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I believe so, checking [another source](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/annotated-posts?tab=locked&filter=merged) we didn't merge any questions this year.

Answer (score 9):

## 2020 vs. 2021 Comparison for RPG.se

[image]

[image]

[image]

Meta posts:

[2017 stats](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7022/52137)

[2018 stats](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8680/8610)

[2019 stats](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/2019-a-year-in-moderation)

[2020 Stats](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11355/2020-a-year-in-moderation)

SEDE Queries:

[Total number of questions, answers per year](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/958293/number-of-questions-answers-and-comments-by-year)

[Comments per year](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/1173867/total-number-of-comments-by-year)

Comment: I find it ominous that we had *half* as many questions & answers as in 2018 or 2019. Do we think that's just because people aren't playing as much during quarantine, or is it a symptom of a larger problem?

Comment: @ObliviousSage There was a notable decline in March 2020, and rates never recovered.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov If only there were an ancient adage about bewaring a particular event in March that we could have heeded.

Comment: @order "Remember, remember, the fifth of March"?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.

Comment: @ObliviousSage can you querry somehow the non-D&D5 question per time? I have the feeling that last year non-that-game questions came further interspaced.

Comment: @Trish search “-[dnd-5e] created:20XX is:question” to get the non-5e questions asked in a year.

Comment: @Trish [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/1541824/number-of-non-5e-questions-per-year) should give you the number of questions each year that did **not** have the [dnd-5e] tag (hopefully; I'm only moderately proficient with SQL and haven't really played around with SEDE before now). ThomasMarkov, I believe Trish was interested in a SEDE query with counts rather than a search on the site itself.

Comment: @ObliviousSage that looks good, but shows a steady decline of non-DnD 5 questions: from 3000 in 2017 to close to 2000 in 18 and 19 to 1600 in 20 and a mere 1100 in 2021. So the feeling that we have become increasingly 5e-centric wasn't wrong!

Comment: @Trish Our total question count is declining as well, so you would need to look at non-5e per total questions.

Comment: @Trish TM is correct, what you really want is to divide the non-5e numbers from that query with the total questions from [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/958293/number-of-questions-answers-and-comments-by-year) to get the percentage of our questions that are 5e vs not-5e over time.

Comment: @ObliviousSage in 2020, that looks like about 1 in 2 was non-DND5e, in 2021, 1 in 4 was not about dnd5e

Comment: @Trish We have a post somewhere tacking those things, I'll look around.

Comment: @Trish I'm showing a small *increase* in the proportion of non-5e question asked in 2021 compared to 2020. 2020 was 33.9% non-5e, 2021 was 35.2% non-5e. (But this maybe because of the advent of pf-2e, I'll do more digging).