# 2022: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, site-statistics

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.

So as we say goodbye to 2022 (and where did January go, right?) and dive head first into 2023, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0TPg.gif). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Role-playing Games over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 87 | 0 |
| Answer flags handled | 436 | 390 |
| Answers flagged | 18 | 807 |
| Bounties canceled | 3 | 0 |
| Comment flags handled | 2,585 | 694 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 7,239 | 3,199 |
| Comments flagged | 39 | 3,241 |
| Comments undeleted | 83 | 0 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 1 | 0 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 44 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 185 | 855 |
| Posts locked | 8 | 74 |
| Posts undeleted | 10 | 81 |
| Posts unlocked | 1 | 2 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 250 | 558 |
| Questions closed | 124 | 527 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 25 | 899 |
| Questions migrated | 5 | 0 |
| Questions protected | 16 | 28 |
| Questions reopened | 25 | 176 |
| Questions unprotected | 0 | 4 |
| Tag synonyms created | 148 | 3 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 146 | 10 |
| Tags merged | 23 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Close votes" queue | 34 | 1,888 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "First answers" queue | 14 | 666 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "First questions" queue | 9 | 401 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Late answers" queue | 9 | 292 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Low quality posts" queue | 9 | 657 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Reopen votes" queue | 17 | 854 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Suggested edits" queue | 115 | 1,038 |
| Users contacted | 1 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 1 | 0 |
| Users destroyed³ | 47 | 0 |
| Users suspended² | 1 | 24 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes). Community can handle these flags by at least one person voting to close a question that has a close flag.

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2021: a year in moderation](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11910/2021-a-year-in-moderation)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222022%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386090/208518)

Wishing everyone a happy 2023! ^_^

Comment: is there a way to see the number of discrete visitors and/or active accounts on this site? On the surface, the declining post numbers seems a little concerning, but it could be possible that, given a lot of questions already have an answer here, we might be seeing the site become more of a reference.

Answer (score 6):

## 2021 vs. 2022 Comparison for RPG.se

[image]

[image]

[image]

Meta posts:

[2017 stats](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7022/52137)

[2018 stats](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8680/8610)

[2019 stats](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/2019-a-year-in-moderation)

[2020 Stats](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11355/2020-a-year-in-moderation)

[2021 Stats](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11910/2021-a-year-in-moderation)

SEDE Queries:

[Total number of questions, answers per year](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/958293/number-of-questions-answers-and-comments-by-year)

[Comments per year](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/1173867/total-number-of-comments-by-year)

Comment: Fascinating; significantly fewer questions and answers, but either better questions or gentler moderation. And the percentage of non-5e questions has gone *up*: 2020 had 33.7%, 2021 had 35.2%, and 2022 had 38.4%. So @AncientSwordRage it looks like your balanced efforts paid off ;)

Comment: @ESCE The mods have closed more questions, in absolute numbers, than in 2021. The community, on the other hand, have (just about) halved the number of questions they close. Either better questions or a gentler community. ;)

Comment: Looks like our community moderation efforts declined even more severely than our user base. Well, we will find out if One will bring activity back to bring us more in line with the general stackexchange format decline.

Comment: @Akixkisu It there an overall decline of the use of StackExchange, too?

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin it is complicated, but yes there was, and as far as I can tell the network is somewhat recovering from that decline, but some sites such as ours are affected more.